# PHP Undefined variable: templates in Controller

Tags: php

I have this folder structure for mvc:

```
application
-----------catalog
------------------controller
----------------------------IndexContoller.php
------------------model
----------------------------IndexModel.php
------------------view
------------------language
-----------admin
------------------controller
------------------model
------------------view
------------------language
core
------Controller.php
public
------Index.php
vendor
....
```

In `index.php` I have:

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, true);
define('BASE_PATH', __DIR__ . DS, TRUE);
//Show errors
//===================================
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
define('ABSPATHS', preg_replace('/\\\/', '/', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
$abspath = preg_replace('/\\\/', '/', dirname(__FILE__));

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
//Upadte
$templates = new League\Plates\Engine(Config::get('PATH_VIEW'));
```

and autoload using composer PSR4 like this :

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Application\\": "application/","Application\\Core\\": "application/core/","Application\\Catalog\\Model\\": "application/catalog/model/"}
    }
    }
```

Now in `Core Controller` I have:

```
namespace Application\Core;

class Controller
{

    // public $templates;
    /**
     * Construct the (base) controller. This happens when a real controller is constructed, like in
     * the constructor of IndexController when it says: parent::__construct();
     */
    public function __construct()
    { 
        $this->Language = new Language();
    }
}
```

In `controller IndexController` I have:

```
namespace Application\Catalog\Controller;

use Application\Core\Controller as Controller;


class IndexController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Construct this object by extending the basic Controller class
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    /**
     * Handles what happens when user moves to URL/index/index - or - as this is the default controller, also
     * when user moves to /index or enter your application at base level
     */
    public function index()
    {
        echo $templates->render('index/index', ['name' => 'Jonathan']);
    }
}
```

In Action i see this error and autoload not loading class in controller:

> Notice: Undefined variable: templates in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cms/application/catalog/controller/IndexController.php on line 23

How do can i fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error states that `Application\Core\League\Plates\Engine` can not be found. According to your autoload definition `Application\Core` is located at `application/core` but according to you directory structure you supplied that file doesn't exists. You need to ensure the file you're trying to load exists where you've said it is.

As a side note you're using composer's PSR-4 autoload functionality but you aren't conforming to [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)

Comment: you right. I need to run new template class to each/all controller page for render template. I change My Q please see this.

Answer (score 0):

You're not explicitly listing vendor folder contents, but I suppose you installed the package https://github.com/thephpleague/plates/blob/master/composer.json through composer... then:

How about placing  in Controller :

```
  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cms/application/core/Controller.php
```

on top the line:

```
  use League\Plates\Engine;
```

Also:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "Application\\": "application/","Application\\Core\\": "application/core/","Application\\Catalog\\Model\\": "application/catalog/model/"}
}
}
```

is too much...

```
The following should be enough:



 autoload": {

    "psr-4": {
        "Application\\": "application/"

    }
}
```

Then add directives like (when needed) in your classes:

```
  use Application\Catalog\Model\...
```

**EDIT**

Var $templates is not accessible within IndexController, try this:

remove form index.php
      $templates = new League\Plates\Engine(Config::get('PATH_VIEW'));

and edit IndexController as follows:

```
namespace Application\Catalog\Controller;

use Application\Core\Controller as Controller;
use League\Plates\Engine;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Construct this object by extending the basic Controller class
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    /**
     * Handles what happens when user moves to URL/index/index - or - as this is the default controller, also
     * when user moves to /index or enter your application at base level
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $templates = new Engine(Config::get('PATH_VIEW'));
        echo $templates->render('index/index', ['name' => 'Jonathan']);
    }
}
```

But since I suppose you'll need to use $templates in more controllers you should define

```
  protected $templates = new League\Plates\Engine(Config::get('PATH_VIEW'));
```

in parent class Controller and access to it through

```
   $this->templates
```

in descendants...

Comment: My problem is `use League\Plates\Engine` not work in controller

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Application\Core\League\Plates\Engine' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cms/application/core/Controller.php:31` and line 31 is : `$templates = new League\Plates\Engine(Config::get('PATH_VIEW'));`

Comment: see error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Application\Catalog\Controller\League\Plates\Engine' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cms/application/catalog/controller/IndexController.php:24`

Comment: use League\Plates\Engine;

Comment: Sure with use League\Plates\Engine;